# React-Native Version Mismatch

Tags: react-native, expo

I know there are many posts regarding this, however the other posts do not seem to fix my issue.

[image: Image of Error]

app.JSON

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "25.0.0"
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.52.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.0.3"
  }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So people don't run around in circles suggesting things you've tried, please add all of the suggestions you're attempted that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue after trying different suggestions and failed, I finally got a solution to the problem. For me, I opened the **package.json** file and **change the react-native version to match that of the JavaScript version as shown in the console error** then ran the following commands in the project root:

```
    npm install
    npm start
```

now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's much too late, but I hope my answer is helpful for other viewers.
You only have to install:

```
react-native upgrade
```

and then run your project.